# Determining the current state of a cell

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I know that a subclass of `UITableViewCell` can implement `willTransitionToState` and execute custom code at the time of transition. But is there any way to find the current state of a cell?

If not, should I subclass `UITableViewCell` and define a property `currentState`, which I always update in my `willTransitionToState`? I will then always have a way to know the state of any particular cell.

Seems strange that I can't ask a cell what its current state is (0, 1, 2, or 3).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The current states are `UITableViewCellStateDefaultMask` (0), `UITableViewCellStateShowingEditControlMask` (1), `UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask` (2), and `UITableViewCellStateShowingEditControlMask | UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask` (3).

These states correspond to the values of the properties [`editing`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/editing) and [`showingDeleteConfirmation`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/showingDeleteConfirmation). It can be tested as follows:

```
if (!cell.editing && !cell.showingDeleteConfirmation) {
    // 0 - UITableViewCellStateDefaultMask
} else if (cell.editing && !cell.showingDeleteConfirmation) {
    // 1 - UITableViewCellStateShowingEditControlMask
} else if (!cell.editing && cell.showingDeleteConfirmation) {
    // 2 - UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask
} else if (cell.editing && cell.showingDeleteConfirmation) {
    // 3 - UITableViewCellStateShowingEditControlMask | UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask
}
```

Comment: Many thanks. My end goal is to identify cells which are showing the delete confirmation because the cell was swiped (and not because the editing control was used). Looking at these options, it seems that it won't quite be enough  I tested, and in both cases the state is (3) (the cell and tableview are both `editing` in both scenarios). Back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 8):

For iOS 6, here's my solution:

Works for any of the transition states AND handles the swipe to delete gesture as well.
Place this code in your subclass of UITableviewCell.

```
- (void)willTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state {

    [super willTransitionToState:state];

    if (state == UITableViewCellStateDefaultMask) {

        NSLog(@"Default");
        // When the cell returns to normal (not editing)
        // Do something...

    } else if ((state & UITableViewCellStateShowingEditControlMask) && (state & UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask)) {

        NSLog(@"Edit Control + Delete Button");
        // When the cell goes from Showing-the-Edit-Control (-) to Showing-the-Edit-Control (-) AND the Delete Button [Delete]
        // !!! It's important to have this BEFORE just showing the Edit Control because the edit control applies to both cases.!!!
        // Do something...

    } else if (state & UITableViewCellStateShowingEditControlMask) {

        NSLog(@"Edit Control Only");
        // When the cell goes into edit mode and Shows-the-Edit-Control (-)
        // Do something...

    } else if (state == UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask) {

        NSLog(@"Swipe to Delete [Delete] button only");
        // When the user swipes a row to delete without using the edit button.
        // Do something...
    }
}
```

Comment: In iOS 8.1 SDK (state == UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask) should be changed to (state & UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask) as the higher bit positions are for whatever reason not zero.

Answer (score 0):

The swift version of jhilgert00 with Neil's comment applied:

```
override func willTransitionToState(state: UITableViewCellStateMask) {

    super.willTransitionToState(state)

    if (state == UITableViewCellStateMask.DefaultMask) {
        println("default")
    } else if (state & UITableViewCellStateMask.ShowingEditControlMask != nil)
        && (state & UITableViewCellStateMask.ShowingDeleteConfirmationMask != nil) {
            println("Edit Control + Delete Button")
    } else if state & UITableViewCellStateMask.ShowingEditControlMask != nil {
        println("Edit Control Only")
    } else if state & UITableViewCellStateMask.ShowingDeleteConfirmationMask != nil {
        println("Swipe to Delete [Delete] button only")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting from swift 3 the value of state is an OptionSet, you can use it like this:

```
override func willTransitionToState(state: UITableViewCellStateMask) {
    super.willTransitionToState(state)
    if state.contains(.DefaultMask) {
        print("DefaultMask")
    }
    if state.contains(.ShowingEditControlMask) {
        print("ShowingEditControlMask")
    }
}
```