# UITableViewCell.showingDeleteConfirmation gives NO when the delete-confirmation button is shown

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I swipe on a table view cell to reveal the delete-confirmation button. But once I lift my finger, `showingDeleteConfirmation` gives NO even if the button is still there. (It does give YES when the button is showing up, I mean, before I lift my finger.) Am I missing something, or it's a real bug in iOS?

Following is my test code. (Copy&paste it into ViewController.m of a single-view project and run it in the simulator, and <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> to trigger the NSLog.)

```
#import "ViewController.h"


@interface ViewController () <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@end


@implementation ViewController {
    UITableViewCell *_myCell;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UITableView *myTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 320, 200)];
    myTableView.dataSource = self;
    myTableView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:myTableView];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    _myCell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];
    _myCell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    return _myCell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    NSLog(@"_myCell.showingDeleteConfirmation = %@", _myCell.showingDeleteConfirmation ? @"YES" : @"NO");
}

@end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to documentation:

> Returns whether the cell is currently showing the delete-confirmation button. (read-only)

...

> **When users tap the deletion control** (the red circle to the left of the cell), the cell displays a "Delete" button on the right side of the cell

So first you need to make grid editable

```
[myTableView setEditing:YES];
```

then user taps circle to delete (they not able to swipe left in this mode), and voilà:

```
_myCell.showingDeleteConfirmation = YES
```

While you can expect to use it as you described in your question, they don't promise it.

Comment: Thanks. But it's strange that it does report YES when swiping, I mean, before I lift my finger.

Comment: I agree it is confusing. I see several similar questions on SO, like this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945771/strange-behavior-of-showingdeleteconfirmation-on-uitableviewcell (though it is merely old and I was not able to see exact the same behavior in iOS7). I think you can use technique from this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/12433957/2170171 to understand if Delete is shown instead of `showingDeleteConfirmation`.